# Преобразовать js массивы в JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Есть два js-массива `ids=[11,12,...,18]` и `titles=[Веник,Швабра,...,Пылесос]`

И вот вопрос - как лучше всего преобразовать всё это дело в JSON вот такого вида:

```
'impressions': [    
    {    
      'title': 'Веник',    
      'id': '11'    
    },    
    {    
      'title': 'Швабра',
      'id': '12'    
    }]
```

Хотя бы подскажите направление куда курить мануалы. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предположим, что кол-во элементов в массивах одинаково

```js
const ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const titles = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'];

const result = {
  impressions: ids.map((id, index) => ({id, title: titles[index]})),
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Почитать про [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: ок, спасибо, все классно... а что если содержимое этих массивов меняется при прокрутке страницы? вместо const юзать let, это мне понятно, а еще?

Comment: @alexashko не совсем понял про прокрутку

Comment: ух тут долго объяснять. Эти массивы хранят айди и названия товаров, которые попали в видимую область экрана. Для гугл аналитики. То есть, человек крутит, сейчас в массиве "Веник" и "Швабра", прокрутил ниже - эти товары удалились из массива, а добавились "Пылесос" и "Тапочки". В общем, не суть важно - главное - что содержимое массивов меняется.

Comment: Я сделал, как Вы советовали, все работает, но в консоли я вижу, что в json добавились все товары,, которые на странице, не удаляются прокрученные

Comment: смотря как вы удаляете элементы ( вообще решение в лоб - просто полностью пересоздавать массив с нужными элементами ), если делать по умному, то лучше задайте отдельный вопрос и там все опишите)

Comment: добавляю push удаляю shift... я подозревал, что до меня в этом скрипте что-то наворотили, и мне придется его переписывать, хоть я и не спец в js)) ок, создам новый вопрос, более развернутый

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1123277/279879 вот вопрос с уточнением