# Два массива js объединить в json динамически

Tags: javascript, json

Есть js-скрипт, который следит, какие товары при прокрутке попали в видимую область страницы. Весь скрипт приводить не буду, приведу лишь часть, где моя проблема:

```
if ( //данный товар в видимой области ) {
    if (mass.indexOf(id) == -1){ //проверяем если такого элемента нет в массиве
        mass.push(id);// то добавляем его ID в один массив
        title = document.getElementById('title' + id).innerText; // ищем на странице название этого товара
        mass1.push(title); // и добавляем его в другой массив
        result = {  impressions: mass.map((id, index) => ({id, title: mass1[index]})),};
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); // формируем json
    }
} else { //если товар ушел из видимой области
    if (mass.indexOf(id) == 1){ //проверяем если его ID в массиве
        mass.shift(id); // удаляем айди из массива айди
        title = document.getElementById('title' + id).innerText;
        mass1.shift(title); // удаляем название из массива названий
        result = {  impressions: mass.map((id, index) => ({id, title: mass1[index]})),};
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); // переформировываем json заново
    }
}
```

Как видно из вышесказанного, скрипт формирует 2 массива: `mass` (в котором лежат айдишники товаров) и `mass1` (в котором лежат названия). Причем, содержимое обоих массивов меняется при прокрутке страницы (товары добавляются и удаляются по мере прокрутки страницы).

Моя проблема: в консоли я вижу, что в JSON товары добавляются, но не удаляются, и он только растет по мере прокрутки. Что я сделал не так?

Comment: 1. `индекс оф` выводит нумбер, необходимо использовать тройное равно, 2. гужевая запятая(в конце результа) колит глазик, 3. можно юзануть `else if`, # меньше лестниц - лучше, 4. тоже типа по иф - условия можно компоновать через `&&` и `||`

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего ошибка в условии `(mass.indexOf(id) == 1)`, ибо индекс идет с 0, а ты хочешь еденидцу

Вот рефактор:

```js
let v_olbasty = false;
if(v_olbasty){
    if(mass.indexOf(id) !== -1)return false;
    mass.push(id);
    mass1.push(document.getElementById(`title${id}`).innerText);
    result = {
        impressions: mass.map((id, i)=>({id, title: mass1[i]}))
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
}else{
    if(mass.indexOf(id) === -1)return false;
    mass.shift(id);
    mass1.shift(document.getElementById(`title${id}`).innerText);
    result = {
        impressions: mass.map((id, i)=>({id, title: mass1[i]}))
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
}
```

+еще одна типа: 5. если код не работает, т.е. (например, как в твоем случае)часть условия не выполняется, то ты можешь смело использовать `console.log` хоть к каждой переменной и каждому условию, это вполне нормальная практика, не знаю почему новички брезгуют... в общем ты мог просто добавить `console.log(id, v_olbasty, mass.indexOf(id));` перед первым условием (после `let v_olbasty = false;`)